# parent in a heap has children or not

Tags: c++, tree, heap, children

I am trying to check a Max-Heap to see whether a parent has children or not. My heap is implemented as a vector. At first i wrote a function bool hasChildren(int loc) loc is the location of the parent in the heap.
my main conditional was:

```
if(heap[2*loc + 1] == NULL && heap[2*loc + 2] == NULL)   //if there are children
```

The problem is that you cannot check out of bounds indices... I thought of pointer arithmetic but that is invalid too. Does anybody have a suggestion for how to check whether a parent in a heap has children?

thanks!

Comment: Is that a vector<T> in your implementation? In that case you might want to remove the C tag.

Comment: But shouldn't it be the other way around, where your node has children if at least one child index is non-NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is that you cannot check out of bounds indices

If this is an `std::vector`, you can use its `at` member function and catch the `std::out_of_range` exception.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how large `heap` was `malloc`ed to be? If so, just make sure that 2*loc+1 and 2*loc+2 are within that range. If `heap` was `malloc`ed to have N elements, make sure that 2*loc+1 and 2*loc+2 are less than N:

```
if(((2*loc+1 < N) && (heap[2*loc + 1] == NULL)) &&
   ((2*loc+2 < N) && (heap[2*loc + 2] == NULL)))
```

Comment: hahaha wow... yes I do have access to the heap's size. Thanks so much though!